# Написать функцию, которая будет считать количество дней после тренировок, помогите разобраться, такую задачу я уже находил

Tags: javascript, php

Вы ходите в тренажёрный зал по определённым дням, например вторникам, четвергам, субботам. Известно сегодняшнее число, и сколько тренировок вы хотите посетить, надо найти, сколько пройдёт календарных дней после посещения этого количества тренировок. Например сегодня понедельник 18 апреля 2016 года, вы ходите в зал по вторникам, четвергам и субботам, хотим узнать, сколько дней пройдёт после посещения шести тренировок. В результате должно получиться 13 дней (тренировки 19, 21, 23, 26, 28 и 30 апреля).

Я нашел похожий вопрос, но там пользователь, написал следующую формулу, которая работает не понятно...
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657459/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%ba](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657459/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA)

> ```
> Пример:
>
> 10 тренировок | 3 раза в неделю (пн, ср, пт) | сегодня среда >следовательно (10 - 2) / 3 = 8 / 3 = 2.1 => 2 полных недели + 1 тренька
> ```

Как у вас получается что 8 поделить на 3 получается 2.1? Как бы я не считал это, получается 2.666. Просто тогда вся ваша логика ломается. Был бы благодарен за ответ)

Comment: Читай внимательнее, это не одна десятая. Это две недели и одна тренировка.

Comment: @Эникейщик окей, но тогда как это посчитать арифметически? Это получается логическое деление

Answer (score 0):

Для `K` тренировок в неделю, `N` тренировок всего считаете `W=N/K` (целочисленно) и `T=N%K`.

Затем считаете дни до ближайшей тренировки

```
D = 0
DayofWeek = Today
while not DayofWeek in TrainingDays:
    D++
    DayofWeek = (DayofWeek + 1) % 7
```

Потом увеличиваете результат на `7 * W` (пройдёт `W` целых недель)

Потом идёте таким же образом по дням недели, пока количество тренировок в них не достигнет `Т`

```
TT = 0
while TT < T:
   D++
   if DayofWeek in TrainingDays:
       TT++    
   DayofWeek = (DayofWeek + 1) % 7
```